# Is caching useless in Entity Framework Disconnected scenarios?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My app uses Entity Framework, and am I trying to improve performance by caching database queries.

This means that - other than the 1st result ever for each query - I will be using an EF disconnected entity.

According to [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities), one **HAS** to inquire whether entity is new or not.

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate(BloggingContext context, Blog blog)
{
    //query DB to determine if entity exists or not
    var existingBlog = context.Blogs.Find(blog.BlogId); 

    if (existingBlog == null)
    {
        context.Add(blog);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(existingBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Does this mean my caching attempts are useless, since I cannot avoid querying the database anyway ?

Comment: **Frame challenge:** would you ever cache a *write?*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *caching*? You talk about *caching database queries* and *1st result ever for each query*. Caching queries or query *results* are two quite different things. Also, what you show is just one of several ways to implement an "upsert" action. All in all, to me it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: In theory, the new entity does not have a given Id. Therefore, a check like `if (blog.BlogId == 0)` is sufficient

Comment: I guess caching can be beneficial in Entity Framework disconnected scenarios if used correctly.For instance, if you have a dataset that is frequently accessed but rarely modified, you can store the results in memory to avoid accessing the database each time the data is needed.

Comment: @GertArnold *first **result** ever for each query* means caching the result for each query. Regarding other ways to implement upserts - what are those that do not require queying DB ?

Comment: That scenario is for systems that do not use DB-issued PKs. (I.e. Identity columns) If you use identity columns you don't need to check the DB for an "upsert", you can inspect the Key. If set, assume an update, if not set, an insert. Personally I advise avoiding Upsert methods, favouring explicit insert vs. update methods. Updates should consider the existing data state to detect concurrent edits and avoid stale data overwrites.  The alternative to pre-emptive checking is handling exceptions.

Comment: @StevePy: if you mean by `identity columns` -> `auto-generated keys`, no, I am not using those. So I understand I need to manually check for existence or not in DB.

Comment: First of all, disconnected operations are nothing new. They exist since the late 1990s and in fact, the entire ADO.NET framework was built for disconnected operations. This has nothing to do with caching. Keeping a connection open for 1 hour won't make queries any faster. You don't need to load rows to check if they exist, you can write your queries in a way that works only if a row doesn't exist, eg `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 ... WHERE ID=@id)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: am not quite following you. 1) I can't see anywhere in either my question or the others comments - someone expressing awe with disconnected scenarios. 2) Let's stay focused on EF, although the principles may apply to most architectures for working with DBs: on a connected scenario, things are simple in that changes are tracked and EF will generate all required DB operations for you by the time SaveChanges is called. In Disconnected, tracking is gone, so now you need yourself to determine if this is an insert or update.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: (continuation) The question revolves around this: for determining whether this is an insert or update, am I forced to query the DB ? because if I am - will caching query results (which I am doing manually on top of my EF repository) - something I started doing in an attempt to improve performance - really offer benefits, if I can't let go of querying the DB ?

Comment: @Veverke the title says `Is caching useless in Entity Framework Disconnected scenarios?` The answer is No, and the problem described in the question has nothing to do with disconnected scenarios or caching. It's about optimistic concurrency and ORMs. No matter what technology you use, if you use client-generated PKs, it's always possible for *another* connection to insert the same PK value. That's covered by using the appropriate PKs or UNIQUE constraints and indexes. In the most common scenario though, new items won't have a PK/ID value, so EF or any ORM will consider them new by default

Comment: The question's `InsertOrUpdate` is a bug by the way. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and detects changes to all the entities it tracks. `SaveChanges` commits the UoW by persisting all changes. That `SaveChanges` can easily perform 20 DELETEs and 42 UPDATEs;. EF's `Update` already handles new or updated values. If the PK fields are empty/default, the object is tracked in the `Added` state. If it has a value, it's tracked in the `Modified` state. Since most databases use auto-generated keys, this works fine.

Comment: Problems can occur when your service/application receives an object with its own PK values from another service or API call. The service can't know at this point if that external PK value exists in the database or not. In SQL you could write a script that either inserts or updates an existing row. ORMs can't do this easily - they can't even perform a `Price=Price*1.1` without loading everything. That's why `FromSql` and the new "bulk" update commands exist. Some things just can't be done with ORM and the illusion of working with objects instead of tables breaks down

Comment: How often will *your* application have to handle an entire graph of objects with filled-in PKs though, and not know if they're new or modified? That won't happen in controller actions - the very action tells you whether it's a POST/create or PUT/PATCH/update.